# reading txt file in a object storage using swift client

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the textfile separated by comma from object storage using the following swift client command :

```
import swiftclient
import keystoneclient

obj_read=swift_conn.get_object('container',object_name)

data='{0}'.format(obj_read[1])
```

With this i could read the file, but I am now having problem converting it into pandas dataframe, is there a way to read the textfile using swiftclient in a more easier fashion so that I can convert that file to dataframe directly.

Currently output look like this :

```
 ({u'accept-ranges': u'bytes',
  u'content-length': u'11242996',
  u'content-type': u'binary/octet-stream',
  u'date': u'Tue, 12 Sep 2017 05:24:33 GMT',
  u'etag': u'3a2206bc62f84e5741dcffb14ddd440d',
  u'last-modified': u'Sun, 10 Sep 2017 23:29:14 GMT',
  u'x-timestamp': u'1505086154.28179',
  u'x-trans-id': u'tx000000000000000040918-0059b76f91-1b5fdf1-au-east'},
 "TIMESTAMP","RECORD","PTemp","Batt_volt","WXT520_weather_Avg(1)","WXT520_weather_Avg(2)","WXT520_weather_Avg(3)","WXT520_rain_Tot(1)","WXT520_rain_Tot(2)","WXT520_rain_Avg(3)","WXT520_rain_Tot(4)","WXT520_rain_Tot(5)","WXT520_rain_Avg(6)","WXT520_wind_Avg(2)","WXT520_wind_Avg(5)","ApogeeSp110_SR_down","ApogeeSp110_SR_up","p_OTT_SensorSN","p_OTT_SensorStatus","p_OTT_ErrorCode","p_OTT_SensorTemp","p_OTT_SensorVolt","p_OTT_SampleInt","p_OTT_LaserStripSigAmp","p_OTT_RadarReflectivity","p_OTT_NBofDetectPart","p_OTT_RainIntensity","p_OTT_AccuRainAmount","p_OTT_MOR_visib","p_OTT_Field_N(1)","p_OTT_Field_N(2)","p_OTT_Field_N(3)","p_OTT_Field_N(4)","p_OTT_Field_N(5)","p_OTT_Field_N(6)","p_OTT_Field_N(7)","p_OTT_Field_N(8)","p_OTT_Field_N(9)","p_OTT_Field_N(10)","p_OTT_Field_N(11)","p_OTT_Field_N(12)","p_OTT_Field_N(13)","p_OTT_Field_N(14)","p_OTT_Field_N(15)","p_OTT_Field_N(16)","p_OTT_Field_N(17)","p_OTT_Field_N(18)","p_OTT_Field_N(19)","p_OTT_Field_N(20)","p_OTT_Field_N(21)","p_OTT_Field_N(22)","p_OTT_Field_N(23)","p_OTT_Field_N(24)","p_OTT_Field_N(25)","p_OTT_Field_N(26)","p_OTT_Field_N(27)","p_OTT_Field_N(28)","p_OTT_Field_N(29)","p_OTT_Field_N(30)","p_OTT_Field_N(31)","p_OTT_Field_N(32)","p_OTT_Field_v(1)","p_OTT_Field_v(2)","p_OTT_Field_v(3)","p_OTT_Field_v(4)","p_OTT_Field_v(5)","p_OTT_Field_v(6)","p_OTT_Field_v(7)","p_OTT_Field_v(8)","p_OTT_Field_v(9)","p_OTT_Field_v(10)","p_OTT_Field_v(11)","p_OTT_Field_v(12)","p_OTT_Field_v(13)","p_OTT_Field_v(14)","p_OTT_Field_v(15)","p_OTT_Field_v(16)","p_OTT_Field_v(17)","p_OTT_Field_v(18)","p_OTT_Field_v(19)","p_OTT_Field_v(20)","p_OTT_Field_v(21)","p_OTT_Field_v(22)","p_OTT_Field_v(23)","p_OTT_Field_v(24)","p_OTT_Field_v(25)","p_OTT_Field_v(26)","p_OTT_Field_v(27)","p_OTT_Field_v(28)","p_OTT_Field_v(29)","p_OTT_Field_v(30)","p_OTT_Field_v(31)","p_OTT_Field_v(32)","p_OTT_RawData(1)","p_OTT_RawData(2)","p_OTT_RawData(3)","p_OTT_RawData(4)","p_OTT_RawData(5)","p_OTT_RawData(6)","p_OTT_RawData(7)","p_OTT_RawData(8)","p_OTT_RawData(9)","p_OTT_RawData(10)","p_OTT_RawData(11)","p_OTT_RawData(12)","p_OTT_RawData(13)","p_OTT_RawData(14)","p_OTT_RawData(15)","p_OTT_RawData(16)","p_OTT_RawData(17)","p_OTT_RawData(18)","p_OTT_RawData(19)","p_OTT_RawData(20)","p_OTT_RawData(21)","p_OTT_RawData(22)","p_OTT_RawData(23)","p_OTT_RawData(24)","p_OTT_RawData(25)","p_OTT_RawData(26)","p_OTT_RawData(27)","p_OTT_RawData(28)","p_OTT_RawData(29)","p_OTT_RawData(30)","p_OTT_RawData(31)","p_OTT_RawData(32)","p_OTT_RawData(33)","p_OTT_RawData(34)","p_OTT_RawData(35)","p_OTT_RawData(36)","p_OTT_RawData(37)","p_OTT_RawData(38)","p_OTT_RawData(39)","p_OTT_RawData(40)","p_OTT_RawData(41)","p_OTT_RawData(42)","p_OTT_RawData(43)","p_OTT_RawData(44)","p_OTT_RawData(45)","p_OTT_RawData(46)","p_OTT_RawData(47)","p_OTT_RawData(48)","p_OTT_RawData(49)","p_OTT_RawData(50)","p_OTT_RawData(51)","p_OTT_RawData(52)","p_OTT_RawData(53)","p_OTT_RawData(54)","p_OTT_RawData(55)","p_OTT_RawDa....\n
```

These are just the field names (1st row).I have data in the similar fashion in the other rows... I have more than 1000 columns and more than 10000 cols...

Comment: What does your data look like? Given a snippet of what you read, it should be pretty simple to show you how to convert it.

Comment: Add the output of `print(obj_read[1])` to the question (or `[0]` if you want the first entry).

Comment: I have just added the output in my question. There are other information in index obj_read[0] which i don't need.

Comment: Still not clear what `obj_read[1]` contains, if it is a list of lists, try: `rows = obj_read[1]; df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])`

Comment: Sorry @MartinEvans I will  update my question, please have a look on it.